# Are these two Spark SQL queries the same in terms of logic?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two queries that I think should be doing the same thing logically, but in reality return different results.  The goal is to find rows parsed out of `HTTP` requests that have a `controller_type` like one of a few conditions, and where the `controller_context_id` is not `NULL` or `''`.  If these conditions are met, give the row a value of one, sum all those up, and group them together.  This first query was incorrectly including rows with a `controller_context_id` that weren't populated:

```
SELECT
            TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month') AS request_timestamp,
            account_id,
            account_guid,
            cluster_id,
            shard_id,
            unique_id,
            context_id,
            controller_type,
            controller_context_id,
            concat_user_id,
            user_id,
            COUNT(account_id) AS num_page_views,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'pages%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_pages,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'files%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_files,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'modules%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_modules,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'assignments%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_assignments,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'quizzes%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_quizzes,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'discussion_topics%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_discussion_topics,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'outcome%' AND
                         controller_context_id <> '' AND
                         controller_context_id IS NOT NULL
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_outcomes,
            COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS num_sessions
        FROM requests
        GROUP BY
          TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month'),
          account_id,
          account_guid,
          cluster_id,
          shard_id,
          unique_id,
          context_id,
          context_id,
          controller_type,
          controller_context_id,
          concat_user_id,
          user_id
```

Where this second query does the correct thing:

```
SELECT
            TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month') AS request_timestamp,
            account_id,
            account_guid,
            cluster_id,
            shard_id,
            unique_id,
            context_id,
            controller_type,
            controller_context_id,
            concat_user_id,
            user_id,
            COUNT(account_id) AS num_page_views,
            COUNT(DISTINCT session_id) AS num_sessions,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'pages%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_pages,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'files%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_files,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'modules%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_modules,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'assignments%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_assignments,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'quizzes%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_quizzes,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'discussion_topics%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_discussion_topics,
            SUM(CASE
                    WHEN controller_type LIKE 'outcomes%' AND
                    (CASE
                      WHEN controller_context_id = '' OR
                      controller_context_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                         = 1
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS num_page_views_outcomes
        FROM requests
        GROUP BY
          TRUNC(request_timestamp, 'month'),
          account_id,
          account_guid,
          cluster_id,
          shard_id,
          unique_id,
          context_id,
          controller_type,
          controller_context_id,
          concat_user_id,
          user_id
```

As far as I can tell they should be doing the same thing, the second query just uses a nested `CASE` statement to check for the `NULL` or `''` value.  I'm having trouble understanding the difference, if any, in logic between the two.